# getting funtion undefined on Renderer.js in Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am working on to fetch records on a scroll in custom lookup lightning component, But getting the following error on `doSearch` function, But function is present in helper.js file, Please suggest any advice

**rendrer.js**

```
({
  afterRender: function(component, event, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();

    var didScroll = false;
    var elem = document.getElementById("lookuplist-items");
    elem.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
      didScroll = true;
    });

    var scrollCheckIntervalId = setInterval(
      $A.getCallback(function() {
        if (didScroll && component.isValid()) {
          didScroll = false;
          console.log("scroll", elem);
          if (elem.scrollTop + elem.offsetHeight + 10 >= elem.scrollHeight) {
            console.log(
              "ttt",
              elem.scrollTop,
              elem.offsetHeight,
              elem.scrollHeight
            );
            // component.set(component.get("v.noOfRecords") + 5);
            helper.doSearch(component, event, 10);
          }
        }
      }),
      1000
    );

    component.set("v.scrollCheckIntervalId", scrollCheckIntervalId);
  },

  unrender: function(component, helper) {
    this.superUnrender();

    var scrollCheckIntervalId = component.get("v.scrollCheckIntervalId");

    if (!$A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(scrollCheckIntervalId)) {
      window.clearInterval(scrollCheckIntervalId);
    }
  }
});
```

**Helper.js**

```
 doSearch: function(cmp, event, limit) {
    console.log("inside");
    if (limit) cmp.set("v.noOfRecords", limit);
    debugger;
    // Get the search string, input element and the selection container
    var searchString = cmp.get("v.searchString");
    var inputElement = cmp.find("lookup");
    var lookupList = cmp.find("lookuplist");
    var lookupListItems = cmp.find("lookuplist-items");
    var lookupDiv = cmp.find("lookup-div");
    var strLabel = cmp.get("v.label");
    var enhancedDiv = cmp.find("enhancedDiv");
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tested running the code without using `$A.getCallback` and without using `setInterval` timeout?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm), the parameters are:

```
afterRender: function(component, helper) {
```

Unlike controller  methods, there is no event parameter. Remove this parameter from your function signature, and it should work.